# Remove span using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic loop that generates the output similar to the following snippet. I need to remove `<span><i>` and `<br>` and just leave the text wrapped in link. I've tried the following:

```js
$('#links a').each(function(){
    var this = $(this),
    span = this.find('span'),
    text = span.text();

    span.remove();
    this.append(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="links">
  <a href="/1">
    <span class="inline">
      <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
      <br>Help
    </span>
  </a>

  <a href="/2">
    <span class="inline">
      <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
      <br>Fix
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Not getting expected results. What am I missing?

Comment: Your code looking good. What results are you seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('#links a').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this)
      .empty()
      .append(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="links">
  <a href="/1">
    <span class="inline">
      <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
      <br>Help
    </span>
  </a>

  <a href="/2">
    <span class="inline">
      <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
      <br>Fix
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

First get the text into a variable and then remove the child elements using `empty` method & at the last append the text.

Answer (score 2):

**[`this`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/javascript-reserved-words)** is a reserved keyword in JS. You need to change `this` to something else:

```js
$('#links a').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
    span = $this.find('span'),
    text = span.text();

    span.remove();
    $this.append(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="links">
  <a href="/1">
    <span class="inline">
      <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
      <br>Help
    </span>
  </a>

  <a href="/2">
    <span class="inline">
      <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
      <br>Fix
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```